# Make OS X Mail show the most recent message in conversation

Tags: macos, mail.app

I like how Mail groups related messages together in a "conversation", but I hate how it always by default shows the oldest unread message in a thread--even if it is months old! This has gotten me on a couple of occasions where I will see a new email come in, click it, and see a message from months ago, but not *realize* that I'm not seeing the one that just came in.

Anyone know how to make Mail always scroll to the top/newest message in a conversation when clicking a message?

Answer (score 15):

In Mail preferences, at the bottom of the Viewing pane, under Viewing Conversations, there is a checkbox to Show Most Recent Message At The Top. I think that's what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately this just swaps the chronological order. It doesn't affect which message of a conversation is displayed when you select the message in the list.

Comment: Interestingly, if I check "mark all messages as read when opening a conversation" it gets *closer* to working in that the *next* time I click the conversation it will scroll to the top, but still not the *first* time I click it!

Comment: It worked for me. I think when you open a conversation it just shows the most recent unread message, which is neat.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `defaults`, the command-line interface for user preferences. Open the Terminal app and type:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail ConversationViewSortDescending -bool true
```

If you are using Mojave, you will first have to [grant full disk access to the Terminal app](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/issues/849#issuecomment-436099833).